# Daisydisk reports more than 40GB "still hidden" space on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina, storage, disk-space

[image: Daisydisk scan results]

On my Mac running macOS Catalina, I noticed there were much less and less free space during past several weeks in which I had done little file additions or software installations. Scanning with Daisydisk returns with results as above, with a "still hidden" part of space taking more than 40 GB.

I've tried `tmutil listsnapshots /` and `tmutil listsnapshots /System/Volume/Data` and found there were not a single local snapshot on my machine.

I've looked up about this question on AskDifferent before posting, and unfortunately none of the replies in theses two questions, [Gigabytes of disk space shown as hidden space in DaisyDisk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44877/gigabytes-of-disk-space-shown-as-hidden-space-in-daisydisk) and [MacBook HD “Other” all of a sudden almost full](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42838/macbook-hd-other-all-of-a-sudden-almost-full), solved my problem here.

Does anyone know what caused this "still hidden" space and how may I free it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gigabytes of disk space shown as hidden space in DaisyDisk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44877/gigabytes-of-disk-space-shown-as-hidden-space-in-daisydisk)

Comment: Thanks! I've looked up about this question on AskDifferent before posting, and unfortunately none of the replies in theses two questions, [Gigabytes of disk space shown as hidden space in DaisyDisk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44877/gigabytes-of-disk-space-shown-as-hidden-space-in-daisydisk) and [MacBook HD “Other” all of a sudden almost full](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42838/macbook-hd-other-all-of-a-sudden-almost-full), solved my problem here.

Comment: @dionisokan https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362552/something-taking-up-90gb-of-storage-in-macos-catalina-10-15-beta/362902#362902

Comment: You mention 40 gb short. What is the total space of that drive?